# Need to Replace properties of single sql file using bat file

Tags: sql, batch-file, batch-processing

How do I replace values/properties of a .sql file using input from the .bat file.

Comment: Give at least an example...

Comment: You have to give more information about the task.

Comment: Say for example
Under Sql file I want to execute a command "CREATE USER '%name%@'localhost'; and I want to pass this %name% from a .bat file say SET %name% = xyz ... is it possible ?

Comment: I want to pass the value from a bat at the run time by giving the input from the user side & that I need to set in the sql file.

Answer (score 0):

When calling the batch file, you use %1, %2, etc. to pass parameters.  You can use those same passed parameters in a stored procedure.  So, in the batch file, you will call the command line version of your database (which version?) and run the stored proc.

Here is an example.  The %1 in the batch file is replaced by "sam" which is passed at the command line.

[image]